# d3js - Move x-axis ticks and bars but not the x-axis towards right

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, charts

I want to move x-axis ticks as shown below.
[image]

I have implemented and you can find in the below fiddle.Here I want to move x-axis ticks and respective bar towards right.

[`Fiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/jx2z2t5n/)

[image]
Please any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your question? You haven't made it clear what you want help to do.

Comment: @Razzildinho That's fine.. but I don't think it is appropriate for this to down vote... I can edit the question.

Comment: I have the same question and havemt been able to figure out hove to solve it yet, were you able to find the answer?